# MVC jQuery it increases the quantity each time with .click function but doesnt replace the href at the same time

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, replace, href, cart

I have a product detail page. There are quantity up and quantity down buttons to change how many quantities will be added when the `Add To Cart` button is clicked.

Each time I click the "quantity up button" I want to change the `href` quantity so I can send the quantity info to the controller.

What is wrong here? Each time I click the quantity up button I get the correct increased quantity info like 2,3,4 etc. but each time I get `/Home/AddToCart/1002?quantity=2` href info. `?quantity=2` should change like `?quantity=3` , `?quantity=4` etc.. but doesn't. What am I missing here?

```
$(".cart_quantity_up").click(function () {
        var val;
        var uri;
        var newuri;
        val = $(".cart_quantity_input").val();
        val++;
        uri = $("#addtocart").attr("href");
        newuri = uri.replace("xxxx", val);
        $("#addtocart").attr("href", newuri);
        $(".cart_quantity_input").val(val);
        alert(newuri);
});
```

xxxx represent a value to be changed later in jquery

Comment: `val()` returns a string, not a number. What is `"xxxx"` supposed to do?

Comment: xxxx represent a value to be changed later in jquery        <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Home", new { id = Model.Id, quantity = "xxxx" })" id="addtocart" class="btn btn-fefault cart" style="margin-top:13px"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Sepete Ekle</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use parseint
2. Use prop instead of attr

   ```
   $(".cart_quantity_up").click(function () {
       var val;
       var uri;
       var newuri;
       val = parseInt($(".cart_quantity_input").val());
       val++;
       uri = $("#addtocart").prop("href");
       newuri = uri.replace("xxxx", val);
       $("#addtocart").prop("href", newuri);
       $(".cart_quantity_input").val(val);
       alert(newuri);
   });
   ```

Remember, href will be change by this so xxxx will no longer be useable if you call this a second time!

Comment: thanks for you help. you are right. the wrong thing I am doing here is to look for xxxx value second time. I will change the way to send data to the controller using ajax.